# In excel, how can I repeat a group of strings in separate cells, based off a number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I am trying to create a formula to repeat a number of cells, depending on a sequence of numbers.

| Repeated strings | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| sc | 5 |
| sc_en | 4 |
| sc_eu | 5 |
| sc_dk | 4 |
| sc_se | 4 |
|  | 5 |

Using the conditions in the example above, I want the output to be:

| Column A |
| --- |
| sc |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |
| sc |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |
| sc |
| sc_en |
| sc_eu |
| sc_dk |
| sc_se |

Because the first number in the sequence is 5, the full group of strings in the group in column A gets printed. The second number is 4, so the the last 4 strings in the sequence gets printed below the first 5. The third number in the sequence is 5, so the full 5 strings in the sequence get printed. The forth number is 4, so the last 4 digits get printed etc.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`=LET(a,A2:A6, b,B2:B7, DROP(REDUCE(0,b,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TAKE(a,-y)))),1))`

It stacks the last `b`-number of cells from range a, where the values of `b` are iterated row by row.

Answer (score 4):

Using Office 365:

```
=LET(rs,A2:A6,seq,B2:B7,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,BYROW(seq,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,TAKE(rs,-a))))),,"|"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, without `LAMBDA()`, but some array manipulation:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(a,A2:A6,b,ROWS(a),c,B2:B7,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(b,,b,-1)<=TOROW(c),a,NA()),2,1))
```

Comment: That's quite clever. Love it.